# Intermittent ArgumentOutOfRangeException when using AlternativeFrame

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvmcross, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm using WinRTXamlToolkit's AlternativeFrame in a Xamrin/MVVMCross Windows 8.1 application to support animations while doing page navigations.   The animations run fine for the first couple of transitions, but I will intermittently get an Application UnhandledException mid-animation --

> The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)"
>
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: This collection cannot work with
> indices larger than Int32.MaxValue - 1 (0x7FFFFFFF - 1). Parameter
> name: index    at
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ListToBindableVectorAdapter.EnsureIndexInt32(UInt32
> index, Int32 listCapacity)    at
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ListToBindableVectorAdapter.GetAt(UInt32
> index)

That's all I get for the stack trace.  The same animation that works several times will throw the error on a future attempt.   Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this or ideas on how to get more information?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to dig a little further to try to fid out what/where this is - and I hope that you manage to get more stacktrace at some point. Can you get this to repro in a simple test app at all?

Answer (score 1):

The offending views were unnecessarily UI heavy  --  GridViews inside ListViews when simple ItemsControls would have sufficed.  I replaced them and the exception went away.